# Using values() on a filtered Django QuerySet with ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models in a Django project:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.pk, self.title)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.pk, self.title)
```

I created an item, and associated it with two categories:

```
>>> item1 = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> item1.categories.all()
<QuerySet [<Category: 1 - C1>, <Category: 4 - C4>]>
```

I can also use filter() and get expected results:

```
>>> Item.objects.filter(categories__title='C1')
<QuerySet [<Item: 1 - Item1>]>
```

However, when I use values() on that same queryset, only the relationships that have been filtered will be returned:

```
>>> Item.objects.filter(categories__title='C1').values('categories__title')
<QuerySet [{'categories__title': 'C1'}]>
```

compared to:

```
>>> Item.objects.all().values('categories__title')
<QuerySet [{'categories__title': 'C1'}, {'categories__title': 'C4'}]>
```

What am I missing? How can I get the full list of categories?

Answer (score 0):

`values` doesn't work that way when it's on a many-to-many relationship. Your filter is actually creating an INNER JOIN on the intermediate table (that tracks the many-to-many relationships) and `values` is going to be applied after all the related models have been filtered out. Due to that, it won't return you all categories for each `Item` object but only the filtered ones.

You should reverse the order of what you're doing:

```
Item.objects.values('categories__title').filter(categories__title="C1")
```

This will actually create an additional LEFT OUTER JOIN first, and then add the INNER JOIN for the filtering clause.

Note that if you have multiple items returned by your filter, you will end up with a lot of duplicate values for your category titles if the objects' categories overlap. See the [warning at the end of this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - I did not think about the order of the queries, even though I suspected I was doing something wrong.